# How can combine or merge all worksheets within an Excel file into one worksheet using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlwings

I'm trying to merge all worksheet tabs of each excel file within a provided file path into one worksheet. For Example if there's 5 Excel files with multiple amounts worksheet tabs, each Excel file now only contains one merged worksheet tab. I would like to append each of these merged worksheet tabs to a created output file.

My Code below is able to appended all worksheet tabs from the provided source files to an output file but I can't figure out how to merge the worksheet tabs from the source first first. Does anyone have an Idea how I can accomplish this? Please see my code below - Thanks!:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os.path
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

#System Arguments
folder = sys.argv[1]
inputFile = sys.argv[2]
outputFile = sys.argv[3]

# specifying the path to xlsx files
path = r""+folder+""

#Create the new Excel Workbook with nameing convention provided by user
def create_file():
    wb = Workbook()
    wb.save(outputFile)

#Append the NEW or EXISTING Workbook with Input Files and Tabs to the already existing Excel File
def appened_file():
    outputPath = outputFile
    book = load_workbook(outputPath)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outputPath, engine = 'openpyxl', mode="a", if_sheet_exists="new")
    writer.book = book
    for filename in glob.glob(path + "*" + inputFile + "*"):
            print(filename)
            excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
            (_, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)
            (f_short_name, _) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
            for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names:
                df_excel = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name,engine='openpyxl')
                df_newSheets = pd.DataFrame(df_excel)
                df_newSheets.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index=False)                   
    writer.save()
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do but if you just want to work with Excel files, I'd suggest use openpyxl directly and don't use Pandas at all.

Comment: @CharlieClark - Thanks for looking at this Charlie. I'm trying to combine all Worksheets that are within one Workbook into one Worksheet Tab. This is what I'm trying to do first, then I'm trying to take this combined worksheet Tab and write it to a new excel file.

Comment: Well forget about Pandas and just try doing it with openpyxl and ask questions about that, though it should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do what is said in the title, you could do this solely with pandas, as `pd.read_excel(path_input, sheet_name=None)` can read all worksheets of a workbook in one pass:

```
import pandas as pd

path_input = r"test.xlsx"
path_output = r"finished.xlsx"

df_lst = pd.read_excel(path_input, sheet_name=None).values()
df_res = pd.concat(
    [df_.transpose().reset_index().transpose() for df_ in df_lst])
df_res.to_excel(path_output, index=False, header=False)
```

It would also be possible to do this with xlwings or openpyxl, but usually pandas is fast.

**Example with data**
Assume an Excel workbook with three worksheets.

Worksheet1:

```
a   b   c
foo cor wal
bar gra plu
baz ult xyz
qux ply thu
```

Worksheet2:

```
u   v   w   x   y   z
12  92  86  22      80
23  29      74      21
16  10  75  67  61  99
```

Worksheet3:

```
I   II  III IV
1   5   9   1
2   6   0   6
3   7       3
4   8   2   0
```

Final output (after executing this snippet, i.e. after `to_excel`):

```
a   b   c
foo cor wal
bar gra plu
baz ult xyz
qux ply thu
u   v   w   x   y   z
12  92  86  22      80
23  29      74      21
16  10  75  67  61  99
I   II  III IV
1   5   9   1
2   6   0   6
3   7       3
4   8   2   0
```

Comment: Can you please offer some guidance or references for how this could be done using Xlwings? The worksheet tabs become separated and have been running into dataframe errors when trying to use df_result within xlwings

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088621/13968392